# How to Change CSS Content using IF Statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display ON and OFF of the CSS part of the code based on the value given in the database. What I want to know is how do I edit the content of the CSS below (.switch-button:before) to change it to ON or OFF.

I've tried giving each element an ID and using document.getElementById for it but it still doesn't work.

The Circled part is what I want to change based on the database value. Currently, its default (the content in CSS) is set to "OFF".

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRU4v.png)

CSS

```
.switch-button:before {
            content: "OFF";
            color: #ffffff;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 60px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            z-index: 3;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div id="turned_onclass" class="turned_onclass" style="display: none;">
    <center><label><u>On/Off</u></label></center>
    <div class="switch-button">
        <input class="switch-button-checkbox" type="checkbox"></input>
        <label class="switch-button-label" for=""> <span id="turned_onspan" value="<%= devices.turned_on %>" class="switch-button-label-span">ON</span> </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    /* Button Displays ON/OFF depending on Value */
    var turned_onTypeDocument = document.getElementById("turned_onspan");
    var turned_onType = turned_onTypeDocument.getAttribute("value");

    if (turned_onType == 1) {
        document.getElementById("turned_onspan").innerHTML = "ON";
        document.getElementById("turned_onspan").style.content = "OFF";
    }

    if (turned_onType == 0) {
        document.getElementById("turned_onspan").innerHTML = "OFF";
        var turned_onClassContent = document.getElementsByClassName("switch-button-label-span");
        turned_onClassContent.style.content = "ON";
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
</script>
```

Comment: That is because JS isn't "reactive" like the way you expected. If you want for a checkbox to trigger state changes, you will need to listen events from it. For example, if your case, you will need to listen to the `input` event on the checkbox and then toggle the on/off state based on the element's value.

Comment: What you could do is use JS to toggle a class, and have that class represent the on/off style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's *possible* to dynamically change CSS, a better approach would be to just set up the initial rules properly. For example, you could toggle a class to produce a new `:before` content.

```
.switch-button:before {
    content: "OFF";
    color: #ffffff;
    ....
}
.switch-button.on:before {
    content: "ON";
}
```

And then just do

```
for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('.switch-button-checkbox')) {
  input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    input.parentElement.classList.toggle('on', e.checked);
  });
}
```

```js
for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('.switch-button-checkbox')) {
  input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    input.parentElement.classList.toggle('on', e.checked);
  });
}
```

```css
.switch-button:before {
  content: "OFF";
}

.switch-button.on:before {
  content: "ON";
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-button">
  <input class="switch-button-checkbox" type="checkbox">
</div>
```